# Functional API or Custom Layer keras tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, functional-api

I was building a neural network in tensorflow keras and ended up with the following code as a step in the model:

```
enc = tfkl.Reshape((-1, 20,input_shape[1]))(input_layer)
encoder_output = []
for i in range(enc.shape[1]):
     o = encoder(enc[:, i, ...])
     encoder_output.append(o)
encoder_output = tf.stack(encoder_output, axis=1)
```

The code WORKS FINE. However it is quite long in the summary and in general not very elegant.
I don't know much about functional API and custom layers. But I would like to know if in this case
it's best to use a custom layer or build a functional API block.

Thank you

Comment: Were you able to find the answer? I'm in a similar situation, and like to compute certain steps on my input features, at certain intermediate layers. Calling a function is same, inelegant, and also for some reason, the summary is weird. Every tf operation (concat, pad, subtract, etc.) is being rendered as a separate layer.

Comment: Please have a look at these links for detailed understanding on how the [Functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) and [Custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate) works. Thank you.